splitting field of $x^2-t$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$
The following paragraph is an example on page 566 in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra:

The inseparable extension $\mathbb{F}_2 (x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2 (t)$ where $x^2 - t = 0$ considered in Section 13.5 is not Galois. Any automorphism of this degree $2$ extension is determined by its action on $x$, which must be sent to a root of the equation $x^2-t$. We have already seen that there is only one root of this equation (with multiplicity 2) since we are in a field of characteristic $2$. Hence the extension has only the trivial automorphism. Note that $\mathbb{F}_2 (x)$ is the splitting field for $x^2 - t$ over $\mathbb{F}_2 (t)$, so this example shows the separability condition in Corollary 6 is necessary.

But I am not sure that what does $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ mean, the author says that it is the splitting field of $x^2-t$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$, but isn't it the field of rational functions in the variable $x$ (the field of fractions of the ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$)? And I think that the splitting field of $x^2-t$ is $\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt t)$. So what does $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ mean?

Here $x$ is in fact exactly $\sqrt{t}$, in the same way that $i$ is the name given to $\sqrt{-1}$ in the complex numbers. So $x$ is not a new indeterminate variable like $t$. Writing $x$ instead of $\sqrt{t}$ serves two purposes: it is quicker to write, and sometimes square root expressions are misleading in how one uses them (think about the numerous "$1=-1$" proof attempts using $\sqrt{-1}$).

@JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, there was some typo in the question, it is truly over $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_2$, and I have corrected it. Thanks for your reminding me.

@JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I agree with you. I think it is better for the author to write the square root of $t$ as other letter than $x$, since the author always use $x$ to denote the variable in a polynomial ring.

As you have noted, the splitting field of $x^2 - t$ over $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$ is $\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt{t})$. But also recall the method of constructing field extensions through roots of polynomials. The (arbitrary) symbol $\sqrt{t}$ is just a placeholder for the former variable $x$, and it signifies that $\sqrt{t}$ is a number $x$ that satisfies the condition $x^2 = t$.
Therefore in your case the difference between $\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt{t})$ and $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ is really just one of notation.
A thing to generally keep in mind: Just because something is denoted by the symbol $x$, this does not mean that it is a free variable that does not satisfy any algebraic relations.
I hope this helped. Best,
Clemens

Thanks, it does help!
